# In Python how do you initialize/reinitialize an associative array (dictionary)?

Tags: python, dictionary

In a Python program I'm writing I will use an associative array (dictionary) which will have year values as keys and lists of 12 monthly observations as values.  For example after reading my data into the dictionary I may end up with a dictionary that looks like this (3 keys pointing to 3 lists of twelve values):

```
{ 1953:[34,39,29,12,16,14,35,42,44,31,22,29],
  1954:[30,31,32,11,19,22,31,41,34,37,25,22],
  1955:[35,36,37,15,19,25,30,45,38,39,21,26] }
```

Each time I read data into the dictionary I may have a different number of key/value pairs.  I want to start with an empty dictionary at the start of each iteration of a loop which reads the data from a file (for simplicity assume it's a comma separated list of 13 values, the first of which is the year followed by twelve monthly observation values).  I'm new to Python and would like to learn the best practice for doing this sort of thing in Python.  In Java I would do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Map<String, List<String>> yearToObservationsMap= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        List<String> yearPlusObservations = line.split(",");
        String year = yearPlusObservations.remove(0); 
        yearToObservationsMap.put(year, yearPlusObservations);
    }

    // now I can work with the dictionary to process the data
}
```

My use case is one in which I will need to have a variable number of entries in the dictionary each time I use it, so I want to reinitialize (or empty?) it each time before it's loaded.  For example during one iteration I may have data for 5 years, the next iteration there'll be data for 30 years, and the next there'll be data for 17 years.  So at each iteration I'll want to clear the dictionary.  But do I also want to declare the dictionary in a way that gives it a definite form, i.e. so it'll always be known to have keys which are years and values which are always 12 element lists of integers?

Thanks in advance for your help with understanding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your questions in reverse. You ask:

> But do I also want to declare the dictionary in a way that gives it a definite form, i.e. so it'll always be known to have keys which are years and values which are always 12 element lists of integers?

The answer to this question is no. Python is dynamically typed, and so the kind of type annotations that are necessary in Java are dispensed with. Furthermore, a dictionary can contain a heterogeneous collection of ([immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)) objects as keys, mixing strings with integers, and so on, and can contain literally any objects at all as values.

As far as reinitializing dictionaries, you could just create a new dictionary each time. But there's also the `.clear()` method, which empties the dictionary out. If you don't want to create a new dictionary each time, for whatever reason, use `.clear()`.

You can see details about *how* to do this in other answers, but I thought I'd address more directly what seems to be your actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Just open the file, split by ',' and pass it to a `dict` comprehension...

```
with open('your_file') as fin:
    lookup = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in (line.split(',') for line in fin)}
```

Or, using CSV module (and **correctly** (cough to me), converting to int)

```
with open('test.csv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    lookup = {col[0]:col[1:] for col in (map(int, row) for row in csvin)}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not so concerned about getting it right for the specific example above, as my use case is actually a bit more problematic.  My question is more around how do you best initialize and then reinitialize a dictionary, and do you do anything to give the dictionary a prescribed structure (i.e. "this dictionary will always contain keys which are integers and values which are twelve element lists of integers")?  Maybe as a Python newcomer I'm expecting to need more structure than is required, and I can be looser with this sort of thing than I'm used to when writing Java code.

Comment: @James Yup, you can be much looser - The idea is don't worry about it - just generate the dictionary when you need it with whatever you want as keys (as long as they're hashable) and with whatever you want as values...-  this example generates it from the file in one go, but you're free to do as others have suggested and create an empty dict, then assign line-by-line or however else you want, when you want to...

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
In [4]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
    dic={}
    for line in f:
        spl=line.split(",")
        dic[spl[0]]=map(int,spl[1:]) 
    print dic
   ...:     
   ...:     
{'1955': [35, 36, 37, 15, 19, 25, 30, 45, 38, 39, 21, 26],
 '1954': [30, 31, 32, 11, 19, 22, 31, 41, 34, 37, 25, 22],
 '1953': [34, 39, 29, 12, 16, 14, 35, 42, 44, 31, 22, 29]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic logic

```
answer = {}
with open('path/to/input') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')]
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

If you want to work with several files, each one containing data for a different number of years, Then, wrap this into a function:

```
def getData(infilepath):
    answer = {}
    with open(infilepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')]
            answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
    return answer
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear example.  There's nothing more to do than to just declare/initialize the dictionary using {}?

Comment: @JamesAdams `{}` is the literal syntax for a dictionary, and there's also `dict()` which is the same thing (but can take iterables as parameters and has some class methods etc...), but yup - `d = {}` initialises an empty dict...